# Backendless.initapp Crashes

Tags: build.gradle, backendless

My app crashes on Backendless.initapp on this line:

```
Backendless.initApp(this, "8B896105-6244-894C-FF80-9C8045E66600", "D07AC071-C614-2A0D-FF05-E36C6C98B700");
```

I am using instantApp features and my features Gradle Module looks like so:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage', 'RtlCompat'
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "3g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation group: 'com.backendless', name: 'backendless', version: '5.0.0'

    // required for real-time database and real-time messaging
    implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
        implementation project(':base')
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

I can confirm that I do have the Backendless SDK installed. I am suspecting that it could be a targeting version issue as the sample targets SDK version 26.

Here is the crash log:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1607)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
    at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.ipc.base.MethodInvocationProxy.readReply(PG:2)
    at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.ipc.base.MethodInvocationProxy.invoke(PG:17)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
    at $Proxy37.startService(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1245)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1227)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:581)
    at com.backendless.Backendless.initApp(Backendless.java:196)
    at com.theswazi.hobbyist.feature.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:38)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2530)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5771) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

Comment: Can you add a stacktrace of the crash? There should be a reason of the crash somewhere on the logs. I assume you already found that since you know the exact line where the crash happens.

Comment: I'm added the crash log.

Answer (score 0):

I ran App without Instant Run and it no longer crashes at Backendless.initApp.

**Edit**
It seems that the error occurs with Android version 6 but since I only had one device with version 6 I am not entirely sure. I did try another device with Android version 5.1.1 which worked.

Comment: Glad for you, but this doesn't actually look like a viable solution, since you now lose the InstantApp abilities. From your stacktrace I see the line where the error happens in the Backendless SDK, and if I had an app to reproduce the error I think I could fix it. Can you please prepare such a [minimal sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sure. Here you are and hope it helps: https://github.com/Mabz/BackendlessAuth. Just run with InstantApp.

Comment: I didn't receive that error, unfortunately. Here's what I see in debugger when I'm on the Backendless:196 line: http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1528804400.png
Can you please try to debug and take the same screenshot on this line before the crash?

Comment: I changed phones and didn't receive an error too. The phone where the error occurred was HTC Desire 10 compact Android version 6.0. The phone that worked was a Samsung Galaxy J3 (2016) Android version 5.1.1. Unfortunately, I'm not willing to reset my HTC to factory default settings to see if it's related to that version of Android.

Comment: Did you ever receive the error on emulator? I tested on the emulated Nexus 5X with API level 27. Will try with Android 6, too.